# Disable git staging area

Tags: git

I really don't like the git staging area, it just makes my life unnecessarily confusing.

Is it possible to disable it so that all edited and new files are in a single context? So that git diff shows the diff between the repository and my working directory (and I don't have to also type git diff --cached) and so that git ci checks in my whole working copy (not just the part that's staged).

If not, alternatives (like setting up cofigurations) so that it appears that I don't have a staging are would be great too.

Thanks,
-Shawn

Comment: Since stackoverflow.com seems to have way more posts about git (4448 vs. 118), I asked the same question over there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3834627/disable-git-staging-area

Answer (score 1):

The staging area is a core concept of Git. I also thought it unnecessary at first, but it [can be really useful](http://tomayko.com/writings/the-thing-about-git) when you must commit only some changes.

So my suggestion is either to

- get used to it,
- or switch to [another SCM](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) that doesn't use a staging area.

---

```
git config alias.ci "commit -a"
```

Comment: It is not an option for me to switch to another SCM, I am working with a git repo. I am simply trying to customize one of the design choices I don't like.

Comment: BTW, you don't need to use the staging area to selectively commit only some changes. You can do 'git ci file1 file3' to only commit a few files straight from working copy. The staging area is only another level of indirection that some people might find useful. I don't.

Comment: Hm, thanks for the git config suggestion, that seems like a partial solution.

Comment: @sligocki: 1) [Yes, it is an option.](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HgGit) 2) I was talking about changes in the same file. `git add -p` is much more convenient than diff/un-edit/commit/patch.

Comment: 1) No, HgGit really isn't an option for me. Not only is the repo git, but several tools (to do code reviews, syncing, etc.) are built on top of git. I would have to write completely new tools to use hg and I have no intention of that :/ 2) Thanks for the hint on git add -p, never tried it, but I don't generally find a need to break up commits with such granularity. I can imagine how the staging area *could* be useful, but for me, right now, it isn't, so I'd like to disable it. It appears the answer is that I cannot :(

Comment: As far as I can see this does not answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can (almost) forget about it if you always do "git commit -a ..." (i.e., commit *all* changes to files git has under version control). But now and then you'll need the staging area: Say you have changes to a bunch of files, and only want to checkin some of them. It is handy to be able to go "hack, hack, hack, git add file1, hack hack hack, git add file2, hack hack, git commit -m change1, hack more, git add file1 file2 file3, git commit -m change2"

Comment: I do not like this style of committing because it could mean that an intermediate commit is totally non-functional because it depended on changes not in the work space. I prefer to be able to build and run tests and then commit everything, assuring that each commit builds and runs tests on it's own.

Comment: @sligocki, I heartily agree with you. But that is an issue of _develper_ discipline, not something a tool could hope to enforce.

Comment: @vonbrand: A commit can function as a staging area, so I don't think your argument explains why there is a need for the extra concept (staging area) as you claim.  For example, there could instead have been a flag to git commit that squashes the previous commit together with the local changes.